# How to make POST request using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, post

I'm trying to make a POST request to my database. However, when I use Postman to test if the request is being made, it's giving me back an error,

```
Cannot POST /api/grocery
```

I'm using Model, View, Controller for my project. This is my index file

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const groceryController = require('./Controller/controllerGrocery.js')

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('api/grocery', (req, res) => {
  groceryController.addGrocery(req, res)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

This is my controller file

```
const models = require('../Model/modelGrocery.js')

const addGrocery = (req, res) => {
  const addGrocery = (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send()
    } else {
      res.status(201).end();
    }
  }
  models.addGrocery(req.body, addGrocery)
}

module.exports = {
  addGrocery: addGrocery
}
```

This is my model file that I'm connecting to the database

```
var db = require('../../DB/db.js');

const getGrocery = (doNext) => {
  //query the database
  db.find()
    .then(result => doNext(null, result))
    .catch(err => doNext(err))
    //callback
}

const addGrocery = (grocery, callback) => {
  db.insertOne({
    item: grocery.item,
    quantity: grocery.quantity
  })
    .catch(err => callback(err))
 }

module.exports = {
  addGrocery: addGrocery
}
```

Comment: What is your ../../DB/db.js file?

Answer (score 0):

Change API Path from api/grocery to /api/grocery

```
app.post('/api/grocery', (req, res) => {
  groceryController.addGrocery(req, res)
})
```